# Fail to add trainable_weights in keras

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to implement the layer normalization in a standard fully connected neural network with keras, by writing a new layer. I copy nearly all the code of `Dense` layer and add a function of `layer normalization` and corresponding parameters. My code is as below:

```
class DenseLN(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, init='glorot_uniform', activation='linear', weights=None,
             W_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None,
             W_constraint=None, b_constraint=None, bias=True, input_dim=None, gamma_init=1., **kwargs):
    self.init = initializations.get(init)
    self.activation = activations.get(activation)
    self.output_dim = output_dim
    self.input_dim = input_dim

    def gamma_init_func(shape, c=gamma_init):
        if c == 1.:
            return initializations.get('one')(shape)
        return K.variable(np.ones(shape) * c, **kwargs)
    self.gamma_init = gamma_init_func
    self.beta_init = initializations.get('zero')
    self.epsilon = 1e-5        

    self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
    self.b_regularizer = regularizers.get(b_regularizer)
    self.activity_regularizer = regularizers.get(activity_regularizer)

    self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
    self.b_constraint = constraints.get(b_constraint)

    self.bias = bias
    self.initial_weights = weights
    self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim=2)]

    if self.input_dim:
        kwargs['input_shape'] = (self.input_dim,)
    super(DenseLN, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def ln(self, x):
    m = K.mean(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    std = K.sqrt(K.var(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True) + self.epsilon)
    x_normed = (x - m) / (std + self.epsilon)
    x_normed = self.gamma * x_normed + self.beta
    return x_normed

def build(self, input_shape):
    assert len(input_shape) == 2
    input_dim = input_shape[1]
    self.input_spec = [InputSpec(dtype=K.floatx(),
                                 shape=(None, input_dim))]

    self.gamma = self.gamma_init(input_dim)
    self.beta = self.beta_init(input_dim)

    self.W = self.init((input_dim, self.output_dim),
                       name='{}_W'.format(self.name))
    if self.bias:
        self.b = K.zeros((self.output_dim,),
                         name='{}_b'.format(self.name))
        self.trainable_weights = [self.W, self.gamma, self.beta, self.b]
    else:
        self.trainable_weights = [self.W, self.gamma, self.beta]
    self.regularizers = []
    if self.W_regularizer:
        self.W_regularizer.set_param(self.W)
        self.regularizers.append(self.W_regularizer)

    if self.bias and self.b_regularizer:
        self.b_regularizer.set_param(self.b)
        self.regularizers.append(self.b_regularizer)

    if self.activity_regularizer:
        self.activity_regularizer.set_layer(self)
        self.regularizers.append(self.activity_regularizer)

    self.constraints = {}
    if self.W_constraint:
        self.constraints[self.W] = self.W_constraint
    if self.bias and self.b_constraint:
        self.constraints[self.b] = self.b_constraint

    if self.initial_weights is not None:
        self.set_weights(self.initial_weights)
        del self.initial_weights

def call(self, x, mask=None):
    output = K.dot(x, self.W)
    #output = self.ln(output)
    if self.bias:
        output += self.b
    return self.activation(output)

def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
    assert input_shape and len(input_shape) == 2
    return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

But during `fit`, it got an `TypeError`: `unorderable types: NoneType() < NoneType()`. According to the log message, seems that the reason is the `trainable_weights`:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-429-3ab01558ab51> in <module>()
      3           batch_size=3000,
      4           callbacks=[history],
----> 5           nb_epoch=300)

/home/lcc/anaconda3/envs/sensequant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, nb_epoch, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, **kwargs)
    427                               shuffle=shuffle,
    428                               class_weight=class_weight,
--> 429                               sample_weight=sample_weight)
    430 
    431     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1,

/home/lcc/anaconda3/envs/sensequant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, nb_epoch, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight)
   1079         else:
   1080             ins = x + y + sample_weights
-> 1081         self._make_train_function()
   1082         f = self.train_function
   1083 

/home/lcc/anaconda3/envs/sensequant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _make_train_function(self)
    695 
    696             # get trainable weights
--> 697             trainable_weights = collect_trainable_weights(self)
    698             training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(trainable_weights, self.constraints, self.total_loss)
    699             updates = self.updates + training_updates

/home/lcc/anaconda3/envs/sensequant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in collect_trainable_weights(layer)
    248     elif layer.__class__.__name__ == 'Model':
    249         for sublayer in layer.layers:
--> 250             weights += collect_trainable_weights(sublayer)
    251     elif layer.__class__.__name__ == 'Graph':
    252         for sublayer in layer._graph_nodes.values():

/home/lcc/anaconda3/envs/sensequant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in collect_trainable_weights(layer)
    256     # dedupe weights
    257     weights = list(set(weights))
--> 258     weights.sort(key=lambda x: x.name)
    259     return weights
    260 

TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < NoneType()
```

Could you please tell me what have I done wrong and how should I fix it? Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Here is the code building the model and fit it:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(DenseLN(12, input_dim=12))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(DenseLN(108))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(DenseLN(108))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
adadelta = Adadelta(lr=0.1, rho=0.95, epsilon=1e-08)
adagrad = Adagrad(lr=0.003, epsilon=1e-08)

model.compile(loss='poisson',
             optimizer=adagrad,
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train_scale,
          Y_train,
          batch_size=3000,
          nb_epoch=300)
```

EDIT2:

I add the `name` attribute to `beta` and `gamma` and seems that the origin error has fixed, but another occurred. The edited code and new log message is as below:

```
self.gamma = K.ones((output_dim,), name='{}_gamma'.format(self.name))
self.beta = K.zeros((output_dim,), name='{}_beta'.format(self.name))

DisconnectedInputError:  
Backtrace when that variable is created:

  File "/home/lcc/anaconda3/envs/sensequant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2809, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/lcc/anaconda3/envs/sensequant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2869, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-464-a90d5bdc38d3>", line 15, in <module>
    model.add(DenseLN(108))
  File "/home/lcc/anaconda3/envs/sensequant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 146, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/home/lcc/anaconda3/envs/sensequant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 458, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "<ipython-input-463-901584f9945c>", line 46, in build
    self.beta = K.zeros((output_dim,), name='{}_beta'.format(self.name))
  File "/home/lcc/anaconda3/envs/sensequant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 77, in zeros
    return variable(np.zeros(shape), dtype, name)
  File "/home/lcc/anaconda3/envs/sensequant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 31, in variable
    return theano.shared(value=value, name=name, strict=False)
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet related to building and running the actual model? Where ever you use the class, rather than the class itself. It seems that you aren't setting any initial weight.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Thanks for your reply! I have added them.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi And the error changed to : `TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < str()`........

Comment: Take a look at the [Keras initializations](https://keras.io/initializations/) guide, or maybe supply the initial weights manually (instead of doing `init='..'` you can just do `weights=[??]`), I haven't actually looked at your model to see what initial weight would make sense.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Indeed the parameter `gamma` and `beta` is initialized by this way :  `def gamma_init_func(shape, c=gamma_init):
        if c == 1.:
            return initializations.get('one')(shape)
        return K.variable(np.ones(shape) * c, **kwargs)
    self.gamma_init = gamma_init_func
    self.beta_init = initializations.get('zero')` . Is there any problem?

Comment: I believe the specific error you have is saying the one of the `weights` attributes in the layer (which has `trainable` set to True) is empty so it can't do any sorting of them during the train step. Maybe looking at the Keras source could might help you: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py -- Or enabling lower level logging to see the actual attributes.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Got it! Thanks! The `name` is empty so they can't be sorted. But now it has another error: `DisconnectedInputError:  
Backtrace when that variable is created` Do you have any idea about it? Thanks